# Getting Transaction not successfully started exception using Spring Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I have a UserProfile entity which I need to save. after saving the entity in the database, I get the following exception:

```
Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
```

Also when I see the table the entity is persisted instead of doing a rollback!

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
public class HibernateUserProfileDAO implements UserProfileDAO {
    private org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public UserProfile getUserProfile(int userId) {
        org.hibernate.classic.Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
        userProfile.setUserName("sury1");
        session.save(userProfile);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return userProfile;
    }
}
```

I'm using hibernate transaction manager

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

and my hibernate config is:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springheatmvn.domain"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>     
</bean>
```

Can anyone pl. tell me what's going on here?

Comment: `@user354161` see edited answer and comment from `Bozho`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you've fall a victim of dual transaction managements. If you are using `Spring Transaction Management` and `Hibernate Transaction Management` together in the same project, you are more likely to have this issue.

Your code then should either be:

**Option 1.** *Hibernate transaction management*

```
public class HibernateUserProfileDAO implements UserProfileDAO {
    private org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public UserProfile getUserProfile(int userId) {
        org.hibernate.classic.Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
        userProfile.setUserName("sury1");
        session.save(userProfile);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return userProfile;
    }
}
```

or **Option 2.** *Spring transaction Management*

```
@Transactional
public class HibernateUserProfileDAO implements UserProfileDAO {
    private org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public UserProfile getUserProfile(int userId) {
        org.hibernate.classic.Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
        userProfile.setUserName("sury1");
        session.save(userProfile);
        session.close();
        return userProfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: yup, either use @Transactional or .beginTransactional(). Furthermore - spring transactions don't support changing the isolation level

Comment: Spring transactions do support isolation level changes, but only in `DataSourceTransactionManager`.

There's also a wrapper class, `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.IsolationLevelDataSourceAdapter` you could use in the Hibernate tx manager. But, if you needed different isolation levels in different places, you have to manage separate Hibernate TX managers, which can be done with AOP but not with `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: Thanks guys!, it worked for me now!!! I used option 2 suggested by @Bitmap. 

Just one correction in option 2, we also need to remove session.close() statement as sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() closes the session automatically. When I had the session.close() statement I got org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed! exception.

Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Could also be a conflict between `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate` and `org.hibernate.Session`.

If you are working on an old project you could find `HibernateTemplate` being used.

If you create a new DAO with a newer way of doing things, like hibernate's `Session`, and use both DAOs on the same function, you will find this error.

**Solution**: Use one or the other. In my case I had to use `HibernateTemplate` in order not to change all ther rest of an old program.